# Going beyond the list of items (angular + primeng)

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have a problem with items on the list.

[image]

```
<p-listbox id="booking-users-list" [options]="items" [style]="{'width':'190px'}" [listStyle]="{'max-height':'238px'}">
    <ng-template let-participant let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
      <div>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 task padd-users-list">
              <span>{{participant}}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <button class="btn-x" class="btn-add-user" type="button" (click)="btnRemove(participant)">x</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-listbox>
```

I want to have a scrollbar effect when there is too much list.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Which version of prime-ng are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can [achieve that with css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow): add `overflow: scroll` to the p-listbox style.

Propably you need to maximalize the container height as well, with `max-height: XXX px;` as well.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)  :)